# PrimeNG Tree with

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have a problem with PrimeNG tree with angular2

Here is my code in the product_tree.component.ts :

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private productsService: ProductsService) {
  this.productsService.getProductsClassesTitles().subscribe(data => {
    /*
    files.data.push({label:"item1",data:"item1",expandedIcon: "", collapsedIcon: "", children: []});
    */
    //  for (let title of data) {
    for (let title of data) {
      this.filesTree4.push({
        label: title,
        children: this.filesTree4

      });
    }
    //   }
  })
}
```

My code in the product_tree.component.html :

```
<p-tree [value]="filesTree4" selectionMode="checkbox" [(selection)]="fileTree4"></p-tree>
```

The problem is that the output is not a tree, but it shows an unordered list like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have missed something to implement primeng in you application.
Add font-awesome in your package.json and save and run `npm install`

```
"dependencies": {
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
}
```

Then if you are using angular cli add this in you angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
   "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
   "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
]
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Are you using angular cli ?